# DBD::mysql fetchrow_array failed: fetch() without execute()?

Tags: mysql, windows, perl, apache, cgi

I am getting the error for the following code:

```
#!C:/usr/bin/perl -w

use CGI;
use strict;
use DBI();
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);


print "content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n\n";

my $q=new CGI;
my $ename=$q->param('ename');
my $email=$q->param('email');

print $q->header;
print "<br>$ename<br>";


#connect to database.
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=test;host=localhost","root","mukesh",
          {'RaiseError' => 1});

eval {$dbh->do("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS emp (ename VARCHAR(20), email VARCHAR(50))")};
print "<br>creating table emp failed: $@<br>" if $@;


my $sql="INSERT INTO emp(ename,email) values('$ename','$email')";

my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql) or die "Can't prepare $sql:$dbh->errstrn";
#pass sql query to database handle


my $rv = $sth->execute() or die "can't execute the query: $sth->errstrn";

my @row;
while (@row = $sth->fetchrow_array) {
print join(", ",@row);
}

$sth->finish();
$dbh->disconnect();

if ($rv==1){
print "<br>Record has been successfully updated !!!<br>";
}else{
print "<br>Error!!while inserting record<br>";
exit;
}
```

Please suggest.what is the problem.
it works fine if i remove this piece of code.

```
my @row;
while (@row = $sth->fetchrow_array) {
print join(", ",@row);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to use the common `SELECT` cycle in DBI - prepare, execute, fetch - for a `non-select` query (`INSERT` in your case). What you probably should do instead is check the result of `execute` directly. Quoting [the doc](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBI/DBI.pm#execute):

> For a non-SELECT statement, `execute` returns the number of rows
>   affected, if known. If no rows were affected, then execute returns
>   "0E0", which Perl will treat as 0 but will regard as true. Note that
>   it is not an error for no rows to be affected by a statement. If the
>   number of rows affected is not known, then execute returns -1.